# How do I timeout Regex operations to prevent hanging in .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, regex, performance, .net-4.5

There are times when being able to limit the pattern matching duration of regex operations could be useful. In particular, when working with user supplied patterns to match data, the pattern might exhibit poor performance due to nested quantifiers and excessive back-tracking (see [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)). One way to apply a timeout is to run the regex asynchronously, but this can be tedious and clutters the code.

According to [what's new in the .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx) it looks like there's a new built-in approach to support this:

> Ability to limit how long the regular expression engine will attempt
> to resolve a regular expression before it times out.

How can I use this feature? Also, what do I need to be aware of when using it?

<sub>Note: I'm [asking *and* answering](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) this question since [it's encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/).</sub>

Comment: Sorry, but this is nothing but self promotion. I would think this is quite off topic for this site.

Comment: @Brandon you're quick to judge, despite the link in my note that supports this. It's on topic and common, as you can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2706) (answered by Jeff Atwood), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845), and [in the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931). Also, this is hardly self promotion as I succinctly cover everything about the topic here and believe it provides accurate info and is of value; I didn't withhold info and say "for more details please refer to my blog."

Comment: You are correct that you did not say exactly: `for more details please refer to my blog`. Instead you said `I recently <CLICK HERE LINK>BLOGGED ABOUT THIS TOPIC</CLICK HERE LINK> in detail.`

Comment: I went ahead and removed references to the blog post. The intention wasn't to promote it. Although it fits within the guidelines of this question on meta it seems it's a sensitive issue: [How do I properly write an answer that references my blog?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-do-i-properly-write-an-answer-that-references-my-blog) I'm happy to share this with the community regardless.

Comment: @Ahmad I removed my down vote. I guess it's just matter of opinion, but I personally think this is pretty tasteless and all around a very poor way to promote yourself. However, to each his own. Cheers.

Comment: @BrandonMoretz (and Trevor): Maybe I am missing something, but I see no issue with somebody not only referring to their blog post on the same topic, but also saying "for more details, please refer to my blog" and then actually providing more information there. Provided, of course, that all of the information needed to solve the issue is contained in the answer here (such that the blog could go away and readers still have the full solution). And that was clearly done in this case. The fact is, there is a length limit on answers, and, being a Q & A site, the focus is not on academic deep-dives.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith (and Brandon): _(cont. from comment above)_ Actually, I see a benefit in people linking to more detailed posts that they  wrote (again, as long as all info needed to solve the problem is here on S.O.). Depending on how one got to this page (S.O. search, a search engine, another blog / article / forum / etc), visiting the poster's blog can be quite helpful. I often follow links because that is a great way to learn, whether about the original topic or something else that sounds interesting, there or via links to yet other sites (e.g. the "**Related**" links to the right -->).

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/netmfteam/2011/08/18/netmf-4-2-regular-expressions/, just as a fyi I pioneered this feature for the microfx and it was recieved so well it was integrated upstream

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I recently researched this topic since it interested me and will cover the main points here. The relevant MSDN documentation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c75he57e%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and you can check out the `Regex` class to see the new overloaded constructors and static methods. The code samples can be run with [Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543).

The `Regex` class accepts a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) to specify the timeout duration. You can specify a timeout at a macro and micro level in your application, and they can be used together:

- Set the `"REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT"` property using the [`AppDomain.SetData` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setdata%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) (macro application-wide scope)
- Pass the `matchTimeout` parameter (micro localized scope)

When the `AppDomain` property is set, all `Regex` operations will use that value as the default timeout. To override the application-wide default you simply pass a `matchTimeout` value to the regex constructor or static method. If an `AppDomain` default isn't set, and `matchTimeout` isn't specified, then pattern matching will not timeout (i.e., original pre-.NET 4.5 behavior).

There are 2 main exceptions to handle:

- [`RegexMatchTimeoutException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexmatchtimeoutexception%28v=VS.110%29.aspx): thrown when a timeout occurs.
- `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: thrown when "`matchTimeout` is negative or greater than approximately 24 days." In addition, a `TimeSpan` value of zero will cause this to be thrown.

Despite negative values not being allowed, there's one exception: a value of -1 ms is accepted. Internally the `Regex` class accepts -1 ms, which is the value of the [`Regex.InfiniteMatchTimeout` field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.infinitematchtimeout%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), to indicate that a match should not timeout (i.e., original pre-.NET 4.5 behavior).

### Using the matchTimeout parameter

In the following example I'll demonstrate both valid and invalid timeout scenarios and how to handle them:

```
string input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
string pattern = @"([a-z ]+)*!";
var timeouts = new[]
{
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4),     // valid
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-10)    // invalid
};

foreach (var matchTimeout in timeouts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input: " + matchTimeout);
    try
    {
        bool result = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern,
                                    RegexOptions.None, matchTimeout);
    }
    catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match timed out!");
        Console.WriteLine("- Timeout interval specified: " + ex.MatchTimeout);
        Console.WriteLine("- Pattern: " + ex.Pattern);
        Console.WriteLine("- Input: " + ex.Input);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

When using an instance of the `Regex` class you have access to the [`MatchTimeout` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matchtimeout%28v=VS.110%29.aspx):

```
string input = "The English alphabet has 26 letters";
string pattern = @"\d+";
var matchTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{
    var re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None, matchTimeout);
    bool result = re.IsMatch(input);
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Completed match in: " + sw.Elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine("MatchTimeout specified: " + re.MatchTimeout);
    Console.WriteLine("Matched with {0} to spare!",
                         re.MatchTimeout.Subtract(sw.Elapsed));
}
catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException ex)
{
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

### Using the AppDomain property

The `"REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT"` property is used set an application-wide default:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT",
                                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

If this property is set to an invalid `TimeSpan` value or an invalid object, a [`TypeInitializationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx) will be thrown when attempting to use a regex.

Example with a valid property value:

```
// AppDomain default set somewhere in your application
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT",
                                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

// regex use elsewhere...
string input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
string pattern = @"([a-z ]+)*!";

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{
    // no timeout specified, defaults to AppDomain setting
    bool result = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
    sw.Stop();
}
catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException ex)
{
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Match timed out!");
    Console.WriteLine("Applied Default: " + ex.MatchTimeout);
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    sw.Stop();
}
catch (TypeInitializationException ex)
{
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("TypeInitializationException: " + ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("InnerException: {0} - {1}",
        ex.InnerException.GetType().Name, ex.InnerException.Message);
}
Console.WriteLine("AppDomain Default: {0}",
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT"));
Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch: " + sw.Elapsed);
```

Using the above example with an invalid (negative) value would cause the exception to be thrown. The code that handles it writes the following message to the console:

> TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' threw an exception.
>
> InnerException: ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Specified argument was
>   out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: AppDomain data
>   'REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT' contains an invalid value or object for
>   specifying a default matching timeout for
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.

In both examples the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` isn't thrown. For completeness the code shows all the exceptions you can handle when working with the new .NET 4.5 `Regex` timeout feature.

#### Overriding AppDomain default

Overriding the `AppDomain` default is done by specifying a `matchTimeout` value. In the next example the match times out in 2 seconds instead of the default of 5 seconds.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT",
                                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

string input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
string pattern = @"([a-z ]+)*!";

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{
    var matchTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    bool result = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern,
                                RegexOptions.None, matchTimeout);
    sw.Stop();
}
catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException ex)
{
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Match timed out!");
    Console.WriteLine("Applied Default: " + ex.MatchTimeout);
}

Console.WriteLine("AppDomain Default: {0}",
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT"));
Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch: " + sw.Elapsed);
```

## Closing Remarks

MSDN recommends setting a time-out value in all regular expression pattern-matching operations. However, they don't draw your attention to issues to be aware of when doing so. I don't recommend setting an AppDomain default and calling it a day. You need to know your input and know your patterns. If the input is large, or the pattern is complex, an appropriate timeout value should be used. This might also entail measuring your critically performing regex usages to assign sane defaults. Arbitrarily assigning a timeout value to a regex that used to work fine may cause it to break if the value isn't long enough. Measure existing usages before assigning a value if you think it might abort the matching attempt too early.

Moreover, this feature is useful when handling user supplied patterns. Yet, learning how to write proper patterns that perform well is important. Slapping a timeout on it to make up for a lack of knowledge in proper pattern construction isn't good practice.

Comment: Nice write up. Even nicer is the expanded version of this info that I found on your blog here: [Regex engine updated to allow timeouts in .NET 4.5](http://softwareninjaneer.com/blog/regex-engine-updated-to-allow-timeouts-in-net-4-5/). Since you don't have a link to the blog post, I figured I would mention it :-).