# RegularExpressions.Match hangs in infinite loop

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

This code hangs in infinite loop.

Any ideas why is that? Is that a bug in .NET? Can I do something about it?

```
Dim urlRegex As New
Regex("((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|ftp[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'"".,<>?«»“”‘’]))",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = urlRegex.Match("<a ""javascript:window.Add(location.href,document.title)"">")
```

Comment: Can you throw a try/catch around it and see if you get any exceptions?

Comment: No exception when executed in Try/Catch block.

Comment: Jiri, it doesn't hang, it just takes a veryyyyy loooong time. So it's not a bug, you should edit your question to ask for ways to optimize your Regex instead.

Comment: Meta-Knight: Are you sure? It run over night and didn't finish.

Comment: Your problem is almost definitely backtracking related. Read the MSDN article here on it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045.aspx#Backtracking . If that makes sense try to implement it. If it doesn't (and even if it does), for the sake of future coders including your future self, rewrite your regex to be something simpler, possibly two or three regexes. Find a larger pattern that you can target, pull out the substring and then parse the smaller parts. And @Meta-Knight is right, it took about 5 minutes to complete on my machine.

Comment: @Jiri: It also took 5 minutes to complete on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I will try to find more optimized regex for finding URLs.

Comment: Id rather do a regex to find "hrefs" and "src" and then get the content, in the html iso of the URL itself, that way you can get absolute and relative Urls too. But probably is a too simplistic aproach... ;-)

Comment: H27: We use this to convert mainly plain text, which can contain HTML snippets. The input can be nearly anything.

Comment: you can time out regex operation
this answer might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616440/1434834

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this is due to excessive backtracking. A good article on this topic can be read here: [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Your options are:

1. Define your pattern better, without nested quantifiers that can cause catastrophic backtracking. This requires you to define your problem better. Build a list of possible inputs and perhaps a better pattern will emerge. Your pattern looks like it's trying to do too much, by specifying what is allowed and what isn't allowed. Sometimes it's possible to simplify the pattern by doing one or the other. What do you want to match?
2. Use .NET 4.5's new `Regex` timeout feature (once it's officially released). Although this isn't a direct solution to your problem it does aid against hanging matches caused by poor patterns. I've covered this here: [How do I timeout Regex operations to prevent hanging in .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616435)