# Regex timelimit in a model

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a register model with a regular expression, but in C# we have Regex.ValidateMatchTimeout to prevent DDoS attacks.
The question is, how implement a regex with timelimit in a model?

A normal regex in my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Email too large.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@(outlook|hotmail|yahoo)\.\w{2,}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid email.")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your example regex isn't prone to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), and is anchored, which means it's *fast*. Do you have any real use case for this?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski uhm? You are saying my regex is well done, no?

Comment: Yes, exactly, which means this particular pattern wouldn't ever timeout. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`RegularExpression` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute) does not allow you to specify a timeout in any way. You could, on the other hand, set the global default timeout. If nothing is configured, the timeout would be infinite.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

More info:

- [How do I timeout Regex operations to prevent hanging in .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616435/how-do-i-timeout-regex-operations-to-prevent-hanging-in-net-4-5)

An alternative would be to create your own attribute, based on the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs).

Comment: In what file must I put AppDomain.Curre...?

Comment: In your `Startup.cs` file, or somewhere that is run before the first regex match.

Comment: Then I can redefine the MATCH_TIMEOUT inside a method, no?
Example: I put 5 seconds in startup, but I put after 20 seconds in my own method. This will affect to all program (all clients) or only to one client??

Comment: You can test it by outputing `new Regex("").MatchTimeout` on some page.

Comment: Yes. `REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT` is global for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is wrong (or perhaps outdated), because you can use `MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds` property, present in RegularExpressionAttribute

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@(outlook|hotmail|yahoo)\.\w{2,}$", MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000, ErrorMessage = "Invalid email.")]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.matchtimeoutinmilliseconds

By the way, even you think your Regex is super-duper smart and awesome and fast, you could still fall pray to a maliciously crafted input that will take your regex for a spin. At scale, that can eventually take your system down.